# Python Multiprocessing with Keras prediction

Tags: python, keras, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

#### Context

A Keras model ([link here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1f0WGCv11uObPziySE2wl6hXYKfyjqXBQ/view?usp=sharing), for the sake of MWE) needs to predict a lot of test data, in parallel.

I define a *cube* as a 3D `numpy.ndarray` of `uint`. Each of its vertical slices is a *column*, which is *npixels* = 128 height, *nbins* = 128 depth.

Each prediction transforms a column in a denoised column (same size).

I'm providing three approaches: a single-threaded, a multiprocessing and a `pathos` package multiprocessing. Both the multi-threaded approaches are not working, and I don't get the reason.

#### Code

```
import keras
import numpy as np
import threading
import pathos.multiprocessing
import multiprocessing


def __res_sum_squares(y_true, y_pred):
    squared_diff = (y_true - y_pred) ** 2
    return keras.backend.sum(squared_diff)


__npixels, __nbins = 128, 128
__shape_col = (__npixels, __nbins)
__shape_nn = (1, __npixels, __nbins, 1)
__model = keras.models.load_model('./model.h5', compile=True, custom_objects={'res_sum_squares': __res_sum_squares})

__max_parallel_predictions = 4
__sema = threading.BoundedSemaphore(value=__max_parallel_predictions)


def __mt_pathos_manager(col_ratio):
    return __denoise(col_ratio[0], col_ratio[1])


def __denoise_frame_mt_pathos(frame_ratios):
    results = pathos.multiprocessing.ProcessingPool().map(__mt_pathos_manager, frame_ratios)
    return results


def __denoise_frame_mt_multiprocessing(frame_ratios):
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    results = pool.map(__denoise, map(lambda col_ratio: col_ratio, frame_ratios))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return results


def __denoise(col, ratio=None):
    """
        :param col: the source column
        :param ratio: logging purposes
        :return: the denoised column
    """
    really_predict = True
    if type(col) is tuple:
        col, ratio = col[0], col[1]
    col_denoise = np.reshape(col, __shape_nn)

    print("{} acquiring".format(ratio))
    __sema.acquire()
    print("{} acquired".format(ratio))
    #  ~    ~  ~  ~  ~  ~  ~  ~  ~  ~ CRITICAL SECTION START ~  ~  ~  ~  ~  ~  ~  ~  ~  ~
    col_denoise = __model.predict(col_denoise) if really_predict else col_denoise
    #  ~    ~  ~  ~  ~  ~  ~  ~  ~  ~ CRITICAL SECTION END   ~  ~  ~  ~  ~  ~  ~  ~  ~  ~
    print("{} releasing".format(ratio))
    __sema.release()
    print("{} released".format(ratio))

    return np.reshape(col_denoise, __shape_col)


def denoise_cube(cube, mp=False, mp_pathos=False):
    """
        :param cube: a numpy 3D array of ncols * npixels * nbins
        :param mp: use multiprocessing
        :param mp_pathos: use pathos multiprocessing
        :return: the denoised cube
    """
    ncol = cube.shape[0]
    ratios = [(ic * 100.0) / ncol for ic in range(0, ncol)]
    frame_ratios = zip(cube, ratios)

    if mp:
        if mp_pathos:
            l_cols_denoised = __denoise_frame_mt_pathos(frame_ratios)
        else:
            l_cols_denoised = __denoise_frame_mt_multiprocessing(frame_ratios)
    else:
        l_cols_denoised = [__denoise(col, ratio) for col, ratio in frame_ratios]
    return l_cols_denoised


if __name__ == "__main__":

    test_cube = np.random.rand(1000, __npixels, __nbins)

    # Single threaded impl: works fine
    denoise_cube(test_cube, mp=False)
    # Multiprocessing Pool: blocks at the eighth "acquired" print
    denoise_cube(test_cube, mp=True, mp_pathos=False)
    # Pathos multiprocessing Pool: blocks at the eighth "acquired" print
    denoise_cube(test_cube, mp=True, mp_pathos=True)
```

#### Analysis

First thing I guessed was that somehow the rush to `__model.predict()` was blocking after 8 calls (= number of cpu cores on test machine).
So I placed a `threading.BoundedSemaphore` with less than 8 accesses. Nothing works.

Single-threaded works as expected:

```
0.0 acquiring
0.0 acquired
0.0 releasing
0.0 released
< ............ >
99.9 acquiring
99.9 acquired
99.9 releasing
99.9 released
```

Multiprocessing (both versions) don't.

```
0.0 acquiring
0.0 acquired
3.2 acquiring
3.2 acquired
6.4 acquiring
6.4 acquired
9.6 acquiring
9.6 acquired
12.8 acquiring
12.8 acquired
16.0 acquiring
16.0 acquired
19.2 acquiring
19.2 acquired
22.4 acquiring
22.4 acquired
< hangs >
```

Wait, where are the `release` prints? Seems that semaphore is not touched, or is being copied for each call, and always reinitialized. Hmm.

So let's look for `really_predict = True` and swap its value: `predict()` call will never be reached in this way.

.... And this works well, great!!! So problem is not entirely addressable to `multiprocessing`, instead to a strange link between `keras` prediction and `multiprocessing` pooling. Any advice ?

Comment: As a note I do not believe `keras'` implementation of predict is threadsafe - or at least it didnt use to be. At the very least you will have to call `_make_predict_function()`.

Comment: I'm not familiar with multiprocess programming as in your example, but perhaps you might want to check out the Keras `Sequence` object which allows to feed data to fit and predict (with `fit_generator()` and `predict_generator()` with safe multiprocessing.